# VBA - how to convert a column to percentages

Tags: vba, excel

I've a code that generates a utilisation formula, however, the output is being displayed in $ when I want it to be in percentages %.

Does anyone know how to make this work via VBA? I know how to easily change this via normal excel but I would like this process to be automated if possible.

What i have so far:

```
'Utilisation rates

With ActiveSheet
    'Determine last row
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    lastrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy the original values from column A to column B
    .Range("H6:H" & lastrow2).Value = .Range("F6:F" & lastrow2).Value

    'Copy / Pastespecial Divide using cell C3
    .Range("C3").Copy
    .Range("H6:H" & lastrow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                          Operation:=xlDivide, _
                                          SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                          Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False



End With
```

Thank you!!! (:

Comment: Another note. You now have asked **MANY** questions with answers, If any of those answers correctly answered your questions then you should mark them as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer that is correct. If you do not do so people will stop answering your questions. Please go back and mark the one correct answer for each of your questions, Or at least provide feedback as to why they did not work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `NumberFormat` option:

```
.Range("H6:H" & lastrow2).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you so much :)

Comment: If you are happy with the solution, please don't forget to accept the answer